# Change drop down list color cell based on range of values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel sheet used to record working hours for some projects. I am trying to change the cell color of the dropdownlist cell based on the color of a range of cells where I write the names of the projects I work on, where every project has a different color. The range is BP2:BP14. I'd like the dropdownlist cell, i.e. A9, to have the same color of the project cell (i.e. a = yellow, etc.). Is it possible with conditional formatting or do I need to use VBA?

[image: sheet]

Comment: Using all capitals is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is pretty rude to do to people you want to help you.

Comment: ok sorry. next time i'll keep attention to this.